# Crawling JavaScript site with selenium (python) returns error: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am new to python and webcrawling in general. I started with BeautifulSoup but quickly learned that sites that use JavaScript cant be crawled with `bs4`, so I started using `selenium`. Selenium, however, also returns an error and cant find the elements (search box) I am trying to scrape. So far I have also learned, that the page I am trying to crawl probably uses `Angular`, which somehow hides the elements I am looking for. Is there a way I could still use selenium or another package to enter search queries and crawl [the site](https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/home)?

Any element I try to find cant be found, ive also tried finding them via `xpath` or `name` with out luck. I believe anything inside `<app-root></app-root>` cant be found simply with selenium.

Here is my code so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
import time
import sys

chrome_driver_path = "path"   
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=chrome_driver_path,
    options=chrome_options
)

useBaseURL = "https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/home"

with webdriver as driver:
    # timeout
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    driver.get(useBaseURL)
    
    searchbox = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ng-tns-c6-0 ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-autocomplete-input ng-star-inserted")
  
    driver.close()
```

Comment: Your class name is actually multiple classes. Use css selector with the tag followed by each name with a . instead of the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following sends keys to that element. Your error was the usage of a compounded class name as a class name. I also added the next click.

```
driver.get(useBaseURL)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, " p-autocomplete > span > input"))).send_keys("AAA")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn.btn-accent.btn-search').click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked just fine. Instead of using the next click, I used  `Keys.RETURN`. Is there a big difference? Anyway it works just fine.

    `search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, " p-autocomplete > span > input")))

    search.send_keys("energy" + Keys.RETURN)`